# How to fill in NA values according to a categorial variable in R

Tags: r, tidyr, missing-data, tibble

I have some NA values in my data that I would like to fill in according to the filename column. In order words, every observation with the same filename should have the same values in the discipline, nativeness, year, and gender columns.

```
structure(list(TA = c("future_perfect", "future_progressive", 
"future_simple", "past_perfect", "past_perfect_progressive", 
"past_progressive", "past_simple", "present_perfect", "present_perfect_progressive", 
"present_progressive", "present_simple", "future_perfect", "future_progressive", 
"future_simple", "past_perfect"), filename = c("BIO.G0.01.1", 
"BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", 
"BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", "BIO.G0.01.1", 
"BIO.G0.02.1", "BIO.G0.02.1", "BIO.G0.02.1", "BIO.G0.02.1"), 
    discipline = c(NA, NA, "BIO", "BIO", NA, "BIO", "BIO", "BIO", 
    "BIO", "BIO", "BIO", NA, NA, "BIO", NA), nativeness = c(NA, 
    NA, "NS", "NS", NA, "NS", "NS", "NS", "NS", "NS", "NS", NA, 
    NA, "NS", NA), year = c(NA, NA, "G0", "G0", NA, "G0", "G0", 
    "G0", "G0", "G0", "G0", NA, NA, "G0", NA), gender = c(NA, 
    NA, "F", "F", NA, "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", NA, NA, "M", 
    NA), n = c(0L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 76L, 34L, 1L, 2L, 265L, 
    0L, 0L, 10L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I know that I can fill() up or down, but some of the missing values are above and some are below, so this would not work. I also know how to fill in the columns based on the value in the filename column.

For instance:

```
mutate(discipline = case_when(
  stri_detect_fixed(filename, "BIO") ~ "Biology",
  stri_detect_fixed(filename, "PHY") ~ "Physics"))
```

However, this would not work for the gender and nativeness columns, as this info is not contained in the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may group by  `fill` and use OP's code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(filename) %>% 
   fill(discipline:gender, .direction = "downup") %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(discipline = case_when(
  stri_detect_fixed(filename, "BIO") ~ "Biology",
  stri_detect_fixed(filename, "PHY") ~ "Physics"))
```

Comment: I see how that works for discipline but how would that work for nativeness and gender? That info is not contained in the filename.

Comment: The same values as every other row that contains the same filename. In other words, every observation with the same filename has the same nativeness, year, gender, and discipline values.

Comment: I don't need to incorporate my original code, as this serves the same purpose. However, how can I be sure the fill has chosen the correct values? This is a tibble of over 5000 rows and I'm concerned that it will sometimes fill according the the wrong filename if that row is adjacent to another row with a different filename.

Comment: @LilyLew that is the reason I used group by fill.  If this is not hte correct output, you need to provide the expectedd output

Comment: I understand now. It's the correct output.